# React + Vite no se muestra el path="/" del Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

Tengo una app de `React` con `Vite` usando `react-router-dom`. Mi problema es que que no se muestra el path  `'./'` del router cuando subo el build al servidor, en mi local funciona perfectamente

La web la tengo que subir a un dominio del tipo :

> dominio.com/devices/seasonal/webviews/miapp/index.html

Para hacer el build de mi app uso este script en el `package.json`:

```
 "build-prod": "vite build --base=/devices/seasonal/webviews/miapp/"
```

En cuanto al código este es mi `main.tsx`

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Este es mi `App.tsx` , los compomentes 'Main, Calls, Tv y About` están bien importados, porque en local funciona bien

```
//imports de otros compomentes
function App() {
 
//resto de codigo...

  return (
    <>
      <Header title={"Prueba"}></Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/calls" element={<Calls />} />
        <Route path="/tv" element={<Tv />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Pues el problema, como os decía, es que cuando subo el build y navego a la url del dominio, solo aparece el la web el componente Header con el título Prueba, Debería aparecer debajo el componente  `Main`,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola no sale ningún error.
Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Porque en mi loca funciona bien y en el servidor no se ve el componente `Main`?